# Why can a killing vector field be determined globally by its value and first derivative at one point?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, vector-fields

It is said in Weinberg's Book, *Gravitation and Cosmology,* page 377, that a [killing vector field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killing_vector_field) (which we a priori assume exists globally) can be uniquely determined by its value and first derivative at one point. The argument uses Taylor expansion at the given point.

My question is, as also stated in the book, the Taylor expansion only holds in a **finite neighborhood** of that given point. Then how can we talk globally? Are we assuming the space-time is compact?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is on page 377 in my book. May be there are different editions.

You only need connectedness of the manifold. That the field is uniquely determined by its value and the value of its derivative at a point is equivalent (by linearity) to the statement that if its value and the value of its derivative are zero at a point, the field is identically zero. To see that note that by the local argument you mention the set of points where the field is zero is open. By assumption it is nonempty, and obviously it is closed. If the manifold is connected only the whole set (and the empty set) is open and closed.

Comment: Beautiful argument!!! Thanks! (The page should be 377, it is a typo, sorry.)